# For sets of reals $A$ and $B$, is it true that $(A + B)' = (\overline{A} + B') \cup (A' + \overline{B})$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ are bounded sets then I want to prove that $(A + B)' = (\overline{A} + B') \cup (A' + \overline{B})$. I'm stuck in both directions and I believe that is not true.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does $A + B$ denote the set of sums $\{a + b : a \in A, b\in B\}$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following

I shall understand $C'$ as the set of all non-isolated points of the space $C$.

Put $A=\Bbb Z$, $B=\sqrt{2}\Bbb Z$. Then both sets $A$ and $B$ are closed discrete subsets of the space $\Bbb R$, so $A'=B'=\varnothing$, $A+B$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so $$(A+B)'=A+B\ne \varnothing=(\overline{A} + B') \cup (A' + \overline{B}).$$

The opposite inclusion also fails. Put $A=B=\Bbb Q$. Then 
$(A+B)'=\Bbb Q'=\Bbb Q$ but both $\overline{A} + B'$ and $A' + \overline{B}$ equals $\Bbb R$.

*Update*. If you understand $C′$ as the set of all non-isolated points of the space $\overline{C}$ then the claim holds. Indeed, put $D=(\overline{A} + B')\cup (A' + \overline{B})$. Then $D\subset \overline{A}+\overline{B}\subset\overline{A+B}$. Let $c\in \overline{A} + B'$. There exists a point $a\in \overline{A}$ and a non-isolated point $b\in \overline{B}$ such that $c=a+b$. Since $b$ is a non-isolated of the set $\overline{B}$, there exists a sequence $\{b_n\}\subset\overline{ B}\setminus\{b\}$, convergent to the point $b$. Then a sequence $\{a+b_n\}\subset \overline{A+B}\setminus\{a+b\}$ converges to the point $a+b=c$. So $c$ is a non-isolated point of the set $\overline{A+B}$. The inclusion   $(A' + \overline{B})\subset (A+B)’$ can be proved similarly.

To show the opposite inclusion we use the boundedness of the set $A$. Let $c\in (A+B)’$. Then there exists a sequence $\{c_n\}\subset\overline{A+B}\setminus\{c\}$ such that $|c_n-c|<1/n$ for each $n$. Since $c_n\in \overline{A+B}$, there exist points $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in b$ such that $|a_n+b_n-c_n|<1/n$. Since the set $A$ is bounded, a sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ convergent to a point $a\in\overline{A}$. Then the sequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ converges to a point $c-a=b\in\overline{B}$. If $a\in A’$ or $b\in B’$ then $c\in D$. In the opposite case $a$ is an isolated point of the set $A$ and $b$ is an isolated point of the set $B$. Then both sequences $\{a_{n_k}\}$ and $\{b_{n_k}\}$ stabilize (that is, are eventually constant), so the sequence $\{c_{n_k}\}$ stabilizes too, a contradiction.

Comment: sorry, but there was a typo

Comment: @DiegoSilvera This doesn't matter. :-)

Comment: sorry again, but $A$ and $B$ must be bounded

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Put $A=B=\Bbb Q \cap [0;1]$. Then $A’=A=B=B’$, $(A+B)’=A+B=\Bbb Q \cap [0;2]\ne [0;2]= (\overline{A} + B') = (A' + \overline{B})$

Comment: In that case $A' = B' = [0,1]$

Comment: @DiegoSilvera See the update of the answer.